# Using ubuntu to recover hard drive data (for the non tech savy)

Tags: boot, hard-drive, lenovo

Computer illiterate student looking for help with crashed lenovo thinkpad!

**Abstract**: Basically I want to back up the HDD for this laptop and was told to use Ubuntu to do that but I dont really know where to start.

**Background:**
I have a lenovo thinkpad 11e yoga (refurbished) which has recently crashed, in that it will not boot its windows operating system. I have taken it to a shop in town where they diagnosed it, concluding that there is a low level hardware issue with the mother board. Luckily the machine is still in warranty and lenovo will fix the system board at no cost. Unluckily, in doing so they will inevitably wipe the HDD clean, and wont/dont back it up.

**What I know so far**:
The tech told me I could easily back up the hard drive (which he assured is working fine) and that I should come here (to Ubuntu), rip the software to a CD and use it to pull the files. Either this or pay $209 for the copy he made when the machine is fixed, which would be, but given my financial situation I would rather avoid that cost if I could.

**Concerns**

-I basically have no idea what he is talking about, and haven't used Ubuntu or any other Linux system before.

-I also am, as stated above, essentially computer illiterate as per anything besides using a browser or word processor/spreadsheet, and have had a hard time understanding the terms used here.

-dont want to take on more than I should and risk losing the data or damaging the machine further.

**Please**: If anyone has idiot proof instruction I would greatly appreciate some help. I know that this is probably laughably basic stuff but any help would again be greatly appreciated. If there is any existing documents that someone could point me to that would explain this please let me know!

If anyone has help to offer, please feel free to talk to me like a small child because I assure you I

Thank you much to anyone that's able to help!!

Comment: Maybe you can try this: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/ If you don't want to invest on a  CD, try creating a bootable usb drive. Follow this for creating one: http://www.fit-pc.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_make_Windows_7_bootable_install_USB_stick.

Comment: You may not find this process fun. It's tedious, technical, detailed, likely to take a long time, and may be fruitless. $209 to avoid the experience may be worth the price to get on with your life quickly.

Comment: Sourav Badami, Thank you for those links, they seem very informative and helpful. A couple questions: Do you think I would have any problems using an external usb CD drive to run Ubuntu live on the target laptop? Also, Im assuming that the bootable usb drive (link 2) is to re-install windows and would therefor wipe the drive clean. Is this true?

Comment: Duncan, there is a help desk at my school (University of New Mexico). I might try them monday or tuesday when Im there. Im not sure that they do services like this but they might be able to help walk my dumb butt through the process. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: user535733, I know what you mean and Im half tempted to do so, but with my fixed budget at present, Im willing to try it. I do appreciate the practical advice though, thank you for taking the time to weigh in.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be difficult to support you with this over the Internet.
In what area are you located ?
If you would live near I could help you for free (e.g. by using Clonezilla software), and I'm sure there's lots more Linux users who would do the same.

You didn't specifically mention what backup options you have : CDs ? DVDs ? It would be great if you would have an external usb disk (e.g. 500 Gb disk) to back it up. In your case I would try to find local tech support. Find a Linux User Group in your area, meet with them, bring your laptop, and watch how they make the backup for you on your usb disk. After that they could wipe the personal data from the laptop hard disk.

More on Linux Users Groups :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_user_group

http://lugslist.com

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I hadn't thought about that but i will look and see what is in my area (Santa Fe NM). Thanks also for the links.

Comment: Looks like Santa Fe does have a group so I will be reaching out to them, thanks again for the suggestion. As per your question, the machine has only a usb port, and no cd drive, though I was looking at getting an external. I do have an external hard drive but I assume that it would be more complicated than just plugging it in and pulling files off, as there is as of now no functioning OS on the machine. This means I assume that I would need to load the linux OS onto the laptop and go from there?

Comment: @Brandon Kelley, if you boot with "Live session" from usb stick with Ubuntu installer, choosing "Try before install", you can add an usb disk to copy from your hard driver to the external usb disk. It is also a good idea to get an external usb disk to make regular backups.

Comment: do you know if there is an instructional page on this? Thanks for your continued interest and help